# Optimization of successive processing of large audio collection with several programs

Tags: python, corpus, large-data

I was given a task to process a large collection of audiofiles. Each file must be processed in four steps:

1. convertion from .wav into raw pcm,
2. resampling,
3. quantization
4. coding with one of three speech codecs.

Each step corresponds to a program taking a file as input and returning a file as output. Processing file by file seems to take long. How can I optimize the procedure? E.g. parrallel programming or something? I tried to make use of ramdisk to reduce the time spent to file reading/writing but it didn't give improvement. (Why?) 
I'm writing in Python under Ubuntu Linux. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing to disk is pretty slow. If each program result is being written to disk then it would be better to stop that from happening. Sockets seem like a good fit to me. Read more here: http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html

Parallel program is nice... need more info before I can say much more on this topic. I remember reading a while ago about python not handling threading so efficiently, so that might not be the best bet. As far as I recall it just emulates parallel processing by switching between tasks really gosh darn quickly. so that wont help. This may have changed since I've worked with threading.... Extra processes on the other hand sound like a good idea.

If you need a less-vague answer please supply specifics in your question.

**EDIT**

The thing i read a while ago about threads looks like this: http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock